# can't get the items of a folder in list through Applescript

Tags: applescript

I am not getting the file inside the images folder through this code. How can I get that file's name  in the given variable (filelist)?

```
set p to "/Users/sumeet/Desktop/images/"

set a to POSIX file p

set filelist to (names of items of (POSIX file a))

-- file "Macintosh HD:usr:local:bin:"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work :

```
set a to "Macintosh HD:Users:sumeet:Desktop:images:" as alias
tell application "Finder"
    set filelist to name of every file in a
end tell
```

You have to tell Finder to get the list of items. Also Finder only takes `alias` paths, so you have to change the unix path to an alias (aaa:aaa:aaa:) format.

You could also do it this way :

```
tell application "Finder"
        set filelist to name of every file in folder "images" of desktop
    end tell
```

Comment: Finder can handle `file` objects created using `POSIX file`. You don't have to create them as non-POSIX aliases. As a side note, instead of `set a to "Macintosh HD:Users:sumeet:Desktop:images:" as alias`, I generally recommend `tell app "Finder" to set a to folder "Users:sumeet:Desktop:images" of startup disk` because people can and do modify their startup disk name (I often do). Even better: `tell app "Finder" to set a to folder "images" of desktop`

Answer (score 1):

```
set p to "/Users/sumeet/Desktop/images/"
set a to POSIX file p
tell application "Finder" to set filelist to name of items of folder a
```

You had a few mistakes. First, you tried to take the `POSIX file` of a `file` object (`a`). You only use this once. Second, you used `names of items` when you actually meant `name of items`. Your way makes more sense grammatically, but is incorrect Applescript. Third, you have to ask Finder to do this for you, since you want to look at the file system.

Comment: can you tell me how to use the Applescript dictionary like i want use the Xcode in that so many items are present and i select the Xcode Project Suit then in this i select the Project class now how can i use  it's Element in my AppleScript

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You should reword it and post it as a new question (since it's unrelated to this one).

Comment: i want to control the xcode with help of the applescript. i want to perform some of the actions like addition some files to the xcode project(EX. add one image to my Xcode project), build the project, clean the project, check any file is present or not?

Comment: Sure. Post that as a new question so later readers can search for it.

Comment: sorry i don't have the permission ask any single question right now.

Comment: What do you mean? There might be a short wait for your IP address, but you should always be able to ask new questions.

Comment: i search a lot for controlling Xcode through applescript but didn't get helpful to me.